# Any sensible ReST editor for Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, restructuredtext

Without plugins, when editing ReST (rst) files in Pycharm with "Wrap on typing" option on (from Editor -> Code Style), lines wrap, which is not what you'd want (as described here https://snakeycode.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/pycharm-and-rst/)

It seems that https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7124?pr=idea is old and broken.

Any good solutions for ReST files in Pycharm?

Comment: Your link above describes how to configure a docutils task in pycharm. Did you ever consider Sphinx? I use it and I am very pleased with it.

Comment: You're right, our editing experience for ReST files isn't as good as it could be. The issue you describe is one that causes me pain too.